# Why is my Materialize sidenav hamburger menu not working?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using a sidebar with a navbar at the top that just displays the hamburger button (when mobile), and a refresh button. It does this fine, but when you click the hamburger icon nothing happens! The sidebar doesn't open. How can I fix this?

Here's my code (the stuff the matters):

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="navbar blue">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a onClick="window.location.reload()"><i class="material-
    icons">refresh</i></a></li>
            </ul>

            <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i 
    class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav sidenav-fixed">
    ...
</ul>
```

And yes, I do have the Materialize CSS and JS, with jQuery version 2.1.1.

Comment: Can you please post your markup to implement jquery and the frameworks javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92cyk9wz/) for a working solution and how to import the needed js.

Code:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      <!-- this part is important! -->
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="navbar-fixed">
      <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper">
             <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
             <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
             <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Remember to initialize the sideNav in your document.ready() function!

This should do the trick.

Comment: It's still not working... is there any chance I'd be able to show you in a discord chat or a screenshot or something? My discord username is eliteAlpaca#5217.

Comment: Yes... and I’ve copied the fiddle exactly... it’s just not working!

Comment: Do you import any other javascript/jquery files **before** executing your init script?

Comment: Yes I did! I’ve followed everything exactly... I just don’t get how it’s not working. It’ll probably be something really obvious though lol

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Do you import any **other** jquery/javascript that is **not** part of the materialize framework?

Comment: Yes - I have Google Analytics and Modernizr.

Comment: Can you move those to the bottom of your page just before closing your body-tag?

Comment: I think I have fixed it, but now the sidenav isn't staying fixed.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Will do! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Add above code in index.html file instead of app.component.html file.

Comment: Please rephrase for clarity. The reference "above code" might be misunderstood in the presence of code in other answers, which might be found above yours.

Comment: Also, some explanation why this helps would improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

take out class fixed and if you want fixed menu do it in css. with that class menu won't work

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.